# Vectors do not satisfy std::ranges::contiguous_range in Eigen 3.4

Tags: c++, eigen, c++20, eigen3, std-ranges

Why does `Eigen::VectorXd` not satisfy the concept `std::ranges::contiguous_range`? That is, `static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<Eigen::VectorXd>);`
does not compile.

Also, is there the possibility to specialize a template to make *Eigen* vectors satisfy the contiguous range concept? For instance, we can specialize `std::ranges::enable_borrowed_range` to make any range satisfy the `std::range::borrowed_range` concept. In other words, is there a way to make the above static assertion compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contiguous ranges have to be opted into. There is no way to determine just by looking at an iterator whether or not it is contiguous or *just* random access. Consider the difference between `deque<int>::iterator` and `vector<int>::iterator` - they provide all the same operations that return all the same things, how would you know unless the `vector<int>::iterator` explicitly told you?

Eigen's iterators do not do this yet. Indeed, before C++20 there was no notion of a contiguous iterator to begin with. That's new with C++20 Ranges.

You can see this if you try to just verify that it is contiguous:

```cpp
using I = Eigen::VectorXd::iterator;
static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<I>);
```

On gcc, the diagnostic indicates:

```cpp
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211221/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:67:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'derived_from<typename std::__detail::__iter_concept_impl<_Iter>::type, std::contiguous_iterator_tag>' [with _Iter = Eigen::internal::pointer_based_stl_iterator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211221/include/c++/12.0.0/concepts:67:28: note:   'std::contiguous_iterator_tag' is not a base of 'std::random_access_iterator_tag'
   67 |     concept derived_from = __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Basically, our category is random-access, not contiguous.

The way for Eigen to do this correctly is to add:

```
 template<typename XprType>
 class pointer_based_stl_iterator
 {
   enum { is_lvalue  = internal::is_lvalue<XprType>::value };
   typedef pointer_based_stl_iterator<typename internal::remove_const<XprType>::type> non_const_iterator;
   typedef pointer_based_stl_iterator<typename internal::add_const<XprType>::type> const_iterator;
   typedef typename internal::conditional<internal::is_const<XprType>::value,non_const_iterator,const_iterator>::type other_iterator;
   // NOTE: in C++03 we cannot declare friend classes through typedefs because we need to write friend class:
   friend class pointer_based_stl_iterator<typename internal::add_const<XprType>::type>;
   friend class pointer_based_stl_iterator<typename internal::remove_const<XprType>::type>;
 public:
   typedef Index difference_type;
   typedef typename XprType::Scalar value_type;
   typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
+  typedef std::contiguous_iterator_tag iterator_concept;
   typedef typename internal::conditional<bool(is_lvalue), value_type*, const value_type*>::type pointer;
   typedef typename internal::conditional<bool(is_lvalue), value_type&, const value_type&>::type reference;
};
```

That would make it a C++20 contiguous iterator.

Alternatively, you could do this yourself externally, although it's not a great idea (really, it's Eigen that should do this correctly), and has to be done earlier than any ranges uses:

```cpp
template <>
struct std::iterator_traits<I> {
    using iterator_concept = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = typename I::value_type;
    using difference_type = typename I::difference_type;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer! I agree that it would be better if *Eigen* fixed this issue, but why do you specifically advise against specializing `std::iterator_traits`? If I know that *Eigen* vectors do model the contiguous range concept, then what is wrong with "notifying" the iterator traits about this fact?

Comment: @fdev Have to do it as early as possible, and every part of your program has to agree on this. It's very easy to end up with odr violations as a result of different parts of a program having different understandings of what `iterator_traits<I>` would be.

Comment: I see! So the only problem would be if I forget to include the header file where I specialize `std::iterator_traits`, but as long as this does not happen I should be safe. In my case, I would do this in a header file that is strictly required by all other files in the repository (it defines the most basic data types). Thus, I should never incur ODR violations!

Comment: Unfortunately, specializing `std::iterator_traits` does not work well if I want to satisfy the contiguous range concept with all *Eigen* vector types, that is, both dynamic and fixed-size vectors, segments, and `Eigen::Ref` objects. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this without listing all possible types?

Comment: @fdev You'd just need to do it for all of the iterator types.

Comment: But it looks like there is one for each *Eigen* type due to CRTP, am I wrong?

Comment: @fdev Not really familiar with Eigen. But... so?

Comment: @fdev How about making this a feature request: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues ?